# How do I handle sharing unique URLs in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am creating a web app to learn Ruby on rails. The app allows users to sign in and draw on a canvas. I want the user to be able to share the masterpiece via a uniquely generated URL specific to the users artwork number. The creator of the artwork should have the option to password protect the URL also. I Don't need the URL to be shareable on Facebook or LinkedIn, twitter or anything like that. Just want a plain URL that can be emailed or texted etc..

What approach should I use to implement this? Are there any gems that allow this functionality easily out of the box? Any design advice and wisdom will be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can have a boolean on your masterpiece model called public. If the picture is public then it can be accessible to anyone. However, if it is not public, then using your return URL will not do anything.

Your public url can be created through a hash. I typically like having the hash token created when the model is created.

`rails g migration add_hash_token_to_masterpieces hash_token`

In your model, you can use the `before_create` method to call a private method taht will update your hash_token with a randomized hex.

```
  before_create :generate_hash_token

private

  def generate_hash_token
    begin
      self.hash_token = SecureRandom.hex
    end while self.class.exists?(hash_token: hash_token)
  end
```

Then in your routes file, you can do something like this

`match "/public/:hash_token" => "masterpieces#public_masterpiece", as: "public"`

Then in your controller you can have a find method of your hash token and have a corresponding view to display the image for the public user. Notice `_and_public` is only finding the ones that are public. Even if the hash is valid, it will not return the record if the masterpiece is not public.

```
def public_masterpiece
  @masterpiece = Masterpiece.find_by_hash_token_and_public(params[:hash_token], true)
  ...
end
```

Then in your masterpiece views, you can have a file called `public_masterpiece.html.erb` which is a specific render for users who do not yet have an authorized account, but still can view the picture. If you are using a gem like cancan for authorization, you will want to make sure that you allow public_masterpiece action.

Comment: Thank you. So what URL exactly will be shareable? And where will all of the unique URLs be saved?

Comment: The URL is dynamically made through the hash token in the model. The URL is HTTP://site/public/hashtoken